# How to pass PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile to google vision api?

Tags: python-3.x, google-vision

On converting PDF file to image using pdf2img:

```
from pdf2image import convert_from_path
import io


def read_pdf(filename):
    # Store Pdf with convert_from_path function
    images = convert_from_path(filename, poppler_path=r'C:\Program Files\poppler-0.68.0\bin',fmt='jpeg')
    for i in range(len(images)):
    # Save pages as images in the pdf
    return images[0]
if __name__ == '__main__':

img = read_pdf('PDF File.pdf')
print(img)
```

*img* is providing me **PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile image mode=RGB size=1653x2339 at 0x16C3B9C3610**.

I want to directly pass the image to google vision(text_document) api for the image to be read and extract text.
However, on running the google vision api, error thrown is **expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not JpegImageFile**

Answer (score 0):

Convert the JPEG file object to memory view by using the code

```
buffer = io.BytesIO()
        images[i].save(buffer, format='JPEG')
        desiredObject = buffer.getbuffer()
        return desiredObject
```

In google vision code, pass the memory view as bytes by converting the memory view into bytes using to_bytes()

```
client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient()

content = infile.tobytes()

image = vision.Image(content=content)
```